# Does Loot Redistribute Among Storages

Tags: clash-of-clans

Though your loot amount appears as a sum of all of the loot in all of your storage, the internal loot of storage are separate. So for example if i started with full storage and i leave a storage outside for people to raid, would i eventually lose all of my loot (Assuming people don't take the inside storage) or will i only lose the loot in that storage?

Comment: http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lionwaffles is somewhat correct. Storages and th have a percentage of your total amount of resources, therefore whenever the amount of that resource changes, the total amount in each storage will update. So collecting loot from collectors, spending loot on research/spells/troops, losing loot from getting attacked, and gaining loot from attacking will all cause the amount of loot per storage to update.

Source: personal experience (tested it in game)

Answer (score 0):

No, loot automatically redistributes itself among storages after you raid someone or get raided.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any proof to support your answer?

Comment: Yes, updated answer with pictures of the storages.

Answer (score 0):

Only after you revisit your village. Why would I say that?

After visiting some of the best players in the world, which were raided, their resource storages had differing images, which mean that they had different loot counts, in which they did. In theory, you lost all the loot available from the storage. But after revisiting your base, the loot should automatically redistribute themselves.

This link should also help: http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Raids

Comment: The redistribution may not be on log on but on change of loot. I didn't pay much attention once but i think i saw two storage balance out when i collected my collectors.