# How do I collect loot stored in my town hall?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How do I collect loot stored in my town hall and how does it get there?

Comment: It *is* a storage. From the TH, you can spend it directly on stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Your town hall simply acts more<sup>1</sup> like a storage as of the TH11 update. It contains up to a certain amount of loot (see [here](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Hall) for a chart on how much) in it that will be obtained if and only if the town hall is destroyed. There is no way to prevent it from being stored in there, nor to remove loot from it.

See [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/251058/does-loot-redistribute-among-storages/251071#251071) for more information on loot distribution.

1: It used to only hold 1k gold and elixir.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot collect the loot from your Th. It is already included in your available amount. Now the CC loot is now in the treasury. Click on the CC to find the treasury icon. Your daily Star bonus willaccumulate there as well. As always, when your CC is full, you lose the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you remember when you were a TH 1 (I know, you were so cute), your only storage was your TH. You didn't have any storage nor buildings at all, only your TH as your entire village. How could you have bought those first gold and elixir storage if you didn't have a way to store those resources already? It functions as both a storage and a building. Just like how you can't control specifically how much gold and elixir is in a storage, you can't "drain" your TH resources into your other storages.